# Расположение рисованных кругов CSS

Tags: css, сss3

Есть стиль, выглядит так:

[image: кружки один по другим]

Нужно сделать, чтобы круги располагались в шахматном порядке, как на картинке ниже.

[image: кружки через один]

Нужно замостить так весь бэкграунд.

```
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #ff72f7 40%, rgba(255,114,247,0) 40%) 100px 100px;
  background-color:white;
  background-size:250px 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```css
.polkaDot {
   background: radial-gradient(circle, #ff72f7 30%, rgba(255,114,247,0) 30%), radial-gradient(circle, #ff72f7 30%, rgba(255,114,247,0) 30%) 125px 125px;
   background-color:white; 
   background-size: 250px 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="polkaDot" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;></div>
```

Для размещения в шахматном порядке размер для `background` = `background-size/2`